# Remove text from Wordpress Login Screen

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have wordpress 3.9.1 installed and am using a plugin to customize the login page.

The plugin is called Branded Login Screen. It is working well and I've been able to edit most of what I'd wanted to.

Now, there's a text just above the form fields that isn't on the default wordpress login screen and I want this text removed.

Please visit the login page [here](http://www.overcheap.com.ng/wp-login.php). The text says:
"BRANDED LOGIN SCREEN 3.2. Enter your login credentials".
I don't want this text.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
     if ( !function_exists( 'add_action' ) ) {
        echo 'This plugin cannot be called directly.';
        exit;
    }

    if ( class_exists( 'Branded_Login_Screen_Pro' ) ) {
                $msg  = '<a href="/wp-admin/plugins.php"><img src="/wp-       content/plugins/branded-login-screen/assets/i/err-header.png" border="0" /></a><br/>';
                $msg .= '<b>Branded Login Screen</b> cannot be activated with \'Branded Login Screen Pro\' active.<br/>';
                $msg .= 'Please deactivate \'Branded Login Screen Pro\' before activating <b>Branded Login Screen.</b><br/>';
                $msg .= '<b>Branded Login Screen</b> has not been activated.<br/>';
                $msg .= '<hr><p>';
                $msg .= '<a href="/wp-admin/plugins.php">Back to the plugins page.</a>';
                $msg .= '</p>';
                wp_die( __( $msg ) );
    }

// constant definition
if( !defined( 'IS_ADMIN' ) )
    define( 'IS_ADMIN', is_admin() );

define( 'BLS_VERSION',      '3.2' );
define( 'BLS_DIR',          WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
define( 'BLS_URL',          rtrim( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ), '/' ) . '/' );
define( 'BLS_UPLOAD_URL',   BLS_URL . 'assets/i' );
define( 'BLS_REDIRECT',     '' );
define( 'BLS_SITE_URL',     get_site_url() ); //wordpress function
define( 'BLS_SITE_NAME',    get_bloginfo() ); //wordpress function
define( 'BLS_BG_IMG_DIR',   BLS_UPLOAD_URL.'/background_image/' );
define( 'BLS_HDR_DIR',      BLS_UPLOAD_URL.'/logo_main' );
define( 'BLS_RHDR_DIR',     BLS_UPLOAD_URL.'/logo_responsive' );

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* you can edit the variables below to make changes to the login form and the images used for    */
/* the background. Please refer to the plugins documentation for examples and explanation        */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

define( 'BLS_LOCATION',     0 ); //used to change location of login form on the page. See documentation for value meanings

define( 'BLS_FULL_SCREEN',  true ); // if using a repeatable background image, set this to false.

define( 'BLS_BG_IMG',       'default-img.jpg' ); // place your 'background'      image in the '/assets/i/background_image' folder.
define( 'BLS_HDR_LOGO',     'header.png' );      // place your 'header logo'     image in the '/assets/i/logo_main'        folder.
define( 'BLS_RHDR_LOGO',    'header-sm.png' );   // place your 'responsive logo' image in the '/assets/i/logo_responsive'  folder.

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    class Branded_Login_Screen
    {

    private $plugin_name    = 'Branded Login Screen';
    private $plugin_version = '3.2';


    public function __construct() {

        register_activation_hook( __FILE__,      array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_activate' ) );
        register_uninstall_hook(  __FILE__,      array( __CLASS__, 'uninstall' ) );

        add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts',     array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_styles' ) );
        add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts',     array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts',     array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_vars' ) );
        add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta',           array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_plugin_meta_links'), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'login_footer',              array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_footer' ) );

        if( IS_ADMIN ) {
            add_action( 'admin_init',            array( __CLASS__, 'branded_login_screen_environment_check' ) );
        }

    } //End of Branded_Login_Screen_Pro __construct


    /**
     * Css additions for login page.
     *
     * Css for login form location on page. Header/responsive header images media queries. Admin Css link.
     *
     * @param
     * @return void
     * @author Kerry Webster
     */
    public function branded_login_screen_styles() {

        switch ( BLS_LOCATION ) {
            case 0: //middle-center ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; }</style>
                <?php
                break;
            case 1: //middle-left ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 0; right:auto; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 0 0 0 40px; }</style>
                <?php
                break;
            case 2: //middle-right ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left:auto; padding: 0 40px 0 0; }</style>
                <?php
                break;
            case 3: //top-center ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 10px; right: 0; bottom: auto; left: 0; padding: 0; }</style>
                <?php
                break;
            case 4: //top-left ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 10px; right:auto; bottom: auto; left: 0; padding: 0 0 0 40px; }</style>
                <?php
                break;
            case 5: //top-right ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 10px; right: 0; bottom: auto; left:auto; padding: 0 40px 0 0; }</style>
                <?php
                break;
            default: //middle-center ?>
                <style>div#login { top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; }</style>
                <?php
        }
        ?>

        <style> .login h1 a { background:url(<?php echo BLS_HDR_DIR . '/' . BLS_HDR_LOGO; ?>) no-repeat scroll center top transparent; } </style>

        <style> @media all and (max-width: 360px), (max-height: 465px){ .login h1 a { background:url(<?php echo BLS_RHDR_DIR . '/' . BLS_RHDR_LOGO; ?>) no-repeat scroll center top transparent; width: 260px; height: 67px; } } </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="custom_button_css"  href="<?php echo plugins_url( '/assets/c/custom-button.css', __FILE__ ); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" id="branded_login_css"  href="<?php echo plugins_url( '/assets/c/branded-login-screen.css', __FILE__ ); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Plugin javacsript enqueue
     *
     * Add the plugins javascript file
     *
     * @param
     * @return void
     * @author Kerry Webster
     */
    public function branded_login_screen_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'branded-login-screen', plugins_url('/assets/j/branded-login-screen.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '1.0',   TRUE );
    }

    /**
     * Get header url and title
     *
     * Header URL and title used for redirection after the user clicks the login logo
     *
     * @param
     * @return void
     * @author Kerry Webster
     */
    public function branded_login_screen_vars() {
        add_filter( 'login_headerurl',   array( __CLASS__, 'bls_login_header_url' ) );
        add_filter( 'login_headertitle', array( __CLASS__, 'bls_login_site_name' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Fullscreen or repeatable background image
     *
     * Inserts the proper .css for the selected background image type
     *
     * @param
     * @return void
     * @author Kerry Webster
     */
    public function branded_login_screen_footer(){

        $imageName = BLS_BG_IMG_DIR.BLS_BG_IMG;

        if ( BLS_FULL_SCREEN ) {
            ?>

            <style>
            body.login { background:#fff url('<?php echo $imageName; ?>') no-repeat fixed top center;

            margin:                  0;
            padding:                 0;

            background-size:         cover;
            -moz-background-size:    cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            }
            </style>

            <?php
        } else {
            ?>

            <style> body.login { background:#fff url('<?php echo $imageName; ?>') repeat fixed top; width:100%; height:100%; } </style>

            <?php
        } ;
    }

    /**
     * Pro version link
     *
     * Link to get the Pro version of the plugin
     *
     * @param $links
     * @param $file
     * @return $links
     * @author Kerry Webster
     */
    public function branded_login_screen_plugin_meta_links( $links, $file ) {
        $plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

        // create link
        if ( $file == $plugin ) {
            return array_merge(
                $links,
                array( '<strong><a href="http://brandedlogin.kerrywebster.com">Get the PRO Version</a></strong>' )
            );
        }
        return $links;
    }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /**
     * Check for proper WordPress and PHP versions
     *
     * Fails plugin load due to version limitations. Suggests upgrades where appropriate.
     *
     * @return void or die
     * @author Kerry Webster
     */
    function branded_login_screen_environment_check()
    {
        $wp_version = get_bloginfo( 'version' );
        $php_ver_needed = '5.2.4';
        $wp_ver_needed = '3.3';
        $php_ok = version_compare( PHP_VERSION, $php_ver_needed, '>=' );
        $wp_ok = version_compare( $wp_version, $wp_ver_needed, '>=' );

        $php_ok_status = $php_ok ? '<span style="color: #00cc00;">OK</span>' : '<span style="color: #ff0000;"><a href="http://us.php.net/downloads.php">Please upgrade your PHP install.</a></span>';
        $wp_ok_status =  $wp_ok  ? '<span style="color: #00cc00;">OK</span>' : '<span style="color: #ff0000;"><a href="http://wordpress.org/download/">Please upgrade your WordPress install.</a></span>';

        if( !$php_ok || !$wp_ok )
        {
            if( IS_ADMIN && ( !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || !DOING_AJAX ) )
            {
                require_once ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
                deactivate_plugins( __FILE__ );
                $msg  = '<a href="/wp-admin/plugins.php"><img src="/wp-content/plugins/branded-login-screen/assets/i/err-header.png" border="0" /></a><br/>';
                $msg  .= '<b>Branded Login Screen</b> requires WordPress version ';
                $msg .= $wp_ver_needed . '+';
                $msg .= ' and PHP version ';
                $msg .= $php_ver_needed . '+';
                $msg .= '. <br/>It has been automatically deactivated.<br/>';
                $msg .= '<hr><p>';
                $msg .= 'Your current installed versions: <br/>';
                $msg .= 'WordPress: ' . $wp_version . ' - ' . $wp_ok_status . '<br/>';
                $msg .= 'PHP: ' . PHP_VERSION . ' - ' . $php_ok_status . '</p>';
                $msg .= '<a href="/wp-admin/plugins.php">Back to the plugins page.</a>';
                wp_die( __( $msg ) );
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Plugin activation
     *
     *  Set plugin defaults
     *
     *  @author     Kerry Webster
     *  @since      3.0
     */
    public function branded_login_screen_activate()
    {

    }




/**
* CLASS PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
*/


    function bls_login_header_url() {
        if ( BLS_REDIRECT != NULL ) {
            return BLS_REDIRECT;
        } else {
            return BLS_SITE_URL;
        }
    }

    function bls_login_site_name() {
        if ( BLS_REDIRECT != NULL ) {
            return BLS_REDIRECT;
        } else {
            return 'Back to ' . BLS_SITE_NAME . ' >> Home Page';
        }
    }
```

Edit: Thanks @Rahil.  Here is the Js code. You were correct I can see the text here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('#backtoblog a').prop('title','Back to Home Page');

    $('form#loginform').prepend('<h2>Enter your login credentials.</h2><br class="clear">');
    $('form#lostpasswordform').prepend('<h2>Enter the required information.You will receive a new password via e-mail.</h2><br class="clear">');
    $('form#resetpassform').prepend('<h2>Enter your new password below.</h2><br class="clear">');

    $('form#registerform').prepend('<h2>Create your own personalized account. A password will be<br\>e-mailed to you.</h2><br class="clear">');
    $('form').prepend('<p class="ver"><a href="http://brandedlogin.kerrywebster.com">Branded Login Screen 3.2</a></p>');

    //TODO: make the alert boxes look prettier. :)

    $("p.reset-pass:contains('Enter your new password below')").hide();

    $("p.reset-pass:contains('Your password has been reset')").show().addClass('backtologin').removeClass('message').removeClass('reset-pass');
});
```

Comment: It appears that the content you want to remove is inserted in the Document on JavaScript runtime. Please share the code of `assets/j/branded-login-screen.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be adding your own stylesheet to the login page:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Styling_Your_Login

You could then display:none the text with CSS (#loginform .ver, #loginform h2)

Comment: I will try this as it looks like a more manageable approach than altering the actual .js file.